# Opening Office Binder OBD file in Mac OS X or Linux

Tags: linux, macos, microsoft-office

I have an old .OBD file (Office Binder).

How can I open it in my Mac OS X or Linux?

Comment: If you can find a Wnidows machine, MS offers an "[Unbinder](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12280)". :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
2. Install Trial Windows virtual machine from this [Github repository](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms).
3. Install Microsoft's [Office 97 Unbind Utilities](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12280)  in the VM.
4. Send your `.ODB` files to the Windows virtual machine and extract them using `unbind.exe`.

Comment: That's not really specifically for OSX, now is it? ;)